# Delete matched pairs in an Array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm attempting to write a game of Go Fish where points are given for matched pairs of cards. However, I can't seem to find a way to remove the matched pairs from the hand.

I have implemented a little loop to remove single cards used in other aspects of the game, as shown here:

```
for ( i = position - 1 ; i < user_size - 1 ; i++)
    {
        user_hand[i] = user_hand[i+1];
        user_count[i]--;
        user_size--;
    }
```

Where the user_size is the number of cards in the user's hand, and the user_count is how many of each of the 13 card values the user holds. I can't find a way to remove pairs of the same valued cards however.

For example if the user_hand was: 2 2 4 5 6 6 6 6 1 2

I would like to remove all but one of the 2's (one pair) and all four of the 6's (two pairs). Leaving the user_hand as: 4 5 1 2. But for the life of me I can't think of a way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are pairs always going to be adjacent in the array?

Comment: I don't get how `user_count` maps to the hand. The way it's used in the loop seems contrary to how you describe it.

Comment: No the pairs aren't always adjacent, that's just a coincidence. User_count is used to keep track of the number of each card value. So I have it lowering by one when the card is 'removed' from the hand.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use 1 array for the cards and one variable to hold the number of cards.
Then you can iterate with a nested loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user_size; i++){
  for (int j = i+1; j < user_size; j++){
    if(user_hand[i] == user_hand[j]){
      /* remove card at index i */
      for(int z = i; z < user_size - 1; z++) user_hand[z] = user_hand[z + 1];
      user_size--;
      /* remove card at index j */
      for(int z = j; z < user_size - 1; z++) user_hand[z] = user_hand[z + 1];
      user_size--;
    }
  }
}
```

But in your example, you also got `user_count[]`. If I understood you right (otherwise please correct me) user_count[] holds how many cards of a specific value the user has on his hand.
So in your example with: 2 2 4 5 6 6 6 6 1 2

```
user_count[0] = 0
user_count[1] = 1
user_count[2] = 3
user_count[3] = 0
user_count[4] = 1
user_count[5] = 1
user_count[6] = 4
```

If that's what `user_count[]` is for, then you could simply do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user_size; i++){
  for (int j = i+1; j < user_size; j++){
    if(user_hand[i] == user_hand[j]){
      int cardNumber = user_hand[i];
      /* remove card at index i */
      for(int z = i; z < user_size - 1; z++) user_hand[z] = user_hand[z + 1];
      user_size--;
      /* remove card at index j */
      for(int z = j; z < user_size - 1; z++) user_hand[z] = user_hand[z + 1];
      user_size--;
      /* decrement user_count by 2 */
      user_count[cardNumber] = user_count[cardNumber] - 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's how user_count[] functions. The code you provided seems like what I'm going for, but I'm confused as to what array[] is?

Comment: @user2933772 array[] was just a mistake - of course it must be user_hand[] there! I corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case reordering cards in users hand is not a problem, you could:

```
int *hand;
int handSize;
...
sort(hand, handSize);                   // 1. sort

int *newHand = malloc(sizeof(int) * handSize);
int i, newHandSize = 0;
for (i = 1; i < handSize; ++i) {
    if (hand[i - 1] == hand[i]) {
        hand[i] = -1;                   // 2. "flag" last value of a pair
        continue;
    }
    newHand[newHandSize] = hand[i - 1]; // 3. copy last examined card to new hand
    newHandSize++;
}
if (hand[handSize - 1] != -1) {         // 4. copy last element if needed
    newHand[newHandSize] = hand[handSize - 1];
    newHandSize++;
}
int* handToFree = hand;
hand = newHand;                         // 5. replace users hand with new hand
free(handToFree);                       // 6. clean up
```

but I don't think it can go under ***O( n*log(n) + n )***

Answer (score 0):

Start by looping through your `user_count` array, and keep calling remove_card twice as long as `user_count[rank] >= 2`:

```
for(int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++)
    while(user_count[rank] >= 2) {
        remove_card(user_hand, user_count, &user_size, rank);
        remove_card(user_hand, user_count, &user_size, rank);
    }
```

For `remove_card`, just find the first matching card, and call your existing routine:

```
void remove_card(int *user_hand, int *user_count, int *user_size, int rank) {
    for(int pos = 0; pos < *user_size; pos++)
         if(user_hand[pos] == rank)
            remove_card_at(user_hand, user_count, user_size, pos+1);
}
```

`remove_card_at` is the routine you provided in your original post to remove a card at a particular position. Note you'll have to turn `user_size` into a pointer and dereference it in order to modify the variable in the calling function.

Also, you should really look into using a structure or class to hold the user's hand, depending on if you're using C or C++.

Comment: 'remove_card' calls 'remove_card_at' which is not declared. You probably wanted to write: 'remove_card' there also.

Comment: Sorry, `remove_card_at` is the routine that the OP provided. I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
void removePairs(int * hand, int size)
{       
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if((hand[i] == hand[j]) && hand[i] != -1)
            { 
                hand[i] = -1; // set card "ready to remove"
                hand[j] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        if(hand[k] != -1)
        {
            printf("%d ", hand[k]); // you can store remaining cards here
        }
    }
}
```